# WHERE IN IF EXISTS Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

When using `WHERE id IN` with a conditional subquery, why does the subquery have to return 1 row? Why does this query work with `limit 1` but not without? How can I make this work?

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/638d30/1

```
/* remove comment around limit 1 and this query works */

SELECT * FROM ForgeRock WHERE `id` IN (
        if(exists (SELECT `fid` FROM `AvailableRock` WHERE `fid` = 2),
           (SELECT `fid` FROM `AvailableRock` WHERE `fid` = 2),
           (SELECT `id` FROM ForgeRock /* LIMIT 1 */)
        )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
select * from ForgeRock where 
(exists(SELECT `fid` FROM `AvailableRock` where `fid` = 1) AND
`id` IN (SELECT `fid` FROM `AvailableRock` where `fid` = 1)) 
OR NOT exists(SELECT `fid` FROM `AvailableRock` where `fid` = 1)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/638d30/12)

Comment: Thanks but that is only returning 1 row still, the problem is when the condition is not met and you want to return all rows instead

Comment: No, it return all rows, when `not exists` triggered, just change all `1` to `2`